# Python reach variable inside loop

Tags: python, dictionary

I am writing a function to get the length of words and count them. Inside this function, I have tried to get intersection of two dictionary but I couldn't reach one of them in properly.

My problem is in line 37 (before the last line), I couldn't reach di_Title which is in line 13 di_Title = dic()

I have tried global variable but it didn't work for me!

My function:

```
def Text_Analyze(Raw_Text):
    Title_Length = []
    Title_Dictionary = []
    Article_Length = []
    Article_Dictionary = []
    Intersection_Dictionary = []
    Title_Info = Raw_Text.PageTitle
    for Each_Line in Title_Info:
        Title = remove_punctuation(Each_Line)
        Title = Title.lower()
        Title = Title.split()
        Title_Length.append(len(Title))
        di_Title = dict()
        for w_Title in Title:
            Root_Title_Split = TurkishStemmer()
            Root_Title_Word = Root_Title_Split.stem(w_Title)
            if Root_Title_Word in di_Title:
                di_Title[Root_Title_Word] = di_Title[Root_Title_Word] + 1
            else:
                di_Title[Root_Title_Word] = 1
        Title_Dictionary.append(di_Title)
    Article_Info = Raw_Text.PageArticle
    for each_Line in Article_Info:
        Article = remove_punctuation(each_Line)
        Article = Article.lower()
        Article = Article.split()
        Article_Length.append(len(Article))
        di_Article = dict()
        for w_Article in Article:
            root_Article_Split = TurkishStemmer()
            root_Article_Word = root_Article_Split.stem(w_Article)
            if root_Article_Word in di_Article:
                di_Article[root_Article_Word] = di_Article[root_Article_Word] + 1
            else:
                di_Article[root_Article_Word] = 1
        Article_Dictionary.append(di_Article)
        Int_Word_Dic = intersect(di_Title, di_Article)
        Intersection_Dictionary.append(Int_Word_Dic)
```

Comment: Adding the error you are receiving would help greatly.

Comment: variables defined within a loop will cease to exist (for practical purposes) once the loop exits. You need to declare them at the beginning of the method (and you can reset them every iteration of the loop)

Comment: @JackWalsh I didn't get any error message. Inside Int_Word_Dic = intersect(di_Title, di_Article) , di_Title produces one value while di_Article produces 146 values. That is my problem.

Comment: @Tacratis each iteration crates different value and I keep them inside of di_Title = dict() .I need to combine di_Title and di_Article iteration each time.

Comment: If you declare them, even just using `di_Title = None` and `di_Article=None` at the beginning of everything, it should work. Each iteration will put the correct values in them, and they will not be destroyed at the end of your loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont get your question but this might do it, as long as each title_info row matches with the same row in article_info

```
def Text_Analyze(Raw_Text):
        Title_Length = []
        Title_Dictionary = []
        Article_Length = []
        Article_Dictionary = []
        Intersection_Dictionary = []
        Title_Info = Raw_Text.PageTitle
        for Each_Line in Title_Info:
            Title = remove_punctuation(Each_Line)
            Title = Title.lower()
            Title = Title.split()
            Title_Length.append(len(Title))
            di_Title = dict()
            for w_Title in Title:
                Root_Title_Split = TurkishStemmer()
                Root_Title_Word = Root_Title_Split.stem(w_Title)
                if Root_Title_Word in di_Title:
                    di_Title[Root_Title_Word] = di_Title[Root_Title_Word] + 1
                else:
                    di_Title[Root_Title_Word] = 1
            Title_Dictionary.append(di_Title)
        Article_Info = Raw_Text.PageArticle
        for c,each_Line in enumerate(Article_Info):
            Article = remove_punctuation(each_Line)
            Article = Article.lower()
            Article = Article.split()
            Article_Length.append(len(Article))
            di_Article = dict()
            for w_Article in Article:
                root_Article_Split = TurkishStemmer()
                root_Article_Word = root_Article_Split.stem(w_Article)
                if root_Article_Word in di_Article:
                    di_Article[root_Article_Word] = di_Article[root_Article_Word] + 1
                else:
                    di_Article[root_Article_Word] = 1
            Article_Dictionary.append(di_Article)
            Int_Word_Dic = intersect(Title_Dictionary[c], di_Article)
            Intersection_Dictionary.append(Int_Word_Dic)
```

Comment: I need to find intersection of di_Title =dict() and di_Article=dict() . I can reach each iteration of di_Article but I can only reach the last iteration of di_Title. I need to reach  each iteration of di_Title . I hope that it makes sense.

Comment: By changing the second loop to `for c,each_Line in enumerate(Article_Info):`,
`c` becomes an index variable that will access each dictionary from the `TitleDictionary` list in the `intersect(Title_Dictionary[c], di_Article)`
`TitleDictionary[0]` is the first `di_Title`, `TitleDictionary[1]` is the secong `di_Title`, etc.

Comment: Does `Title_Info[x]` match with `ArticleInfo[x]` for all numbers x?

Comment: Each Title_Info matches with each Article_Info. They are each row of a data frame.

Comment: This code should do exactly as you need then. On the first loop of `for c,each_Line in enumerate(Article_Info)` it would do `intersect(Title_Dictionary[0], di_Article)` which is the first `di_Title` dictionary, as you appended them to the list in order.

Comment: Thank you @Jack Walsh . This solution works for me!

Answer (score 2):

Variables declared inside a scope (in your case, in a loop) will be inaccessible outside the scope in which it is declared.

You can declare it at a higher scope (in your case, before the loop) and change its value depending on your needs.